# Optimal button placement on top bar of mobile application

Tags: ios, mobile-application

What is the optimal placement for buttons on the top bar of a mobile application (on the profile screen)?

[image]

Currently I have a **Home** button on the top left section and a **Search** & **Find Friend** button on the top right of my page.

The current button placement seems less than ideal, because the user can easily confuse the **Search** and **Find Friend** buttons on the top right. I wanted to ask how it could be improved. Are there particular design principles when it comes to such?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without a doubt, there's only room for 1 button on the right.

The options I see (without understanding the nature of the app):

- If I assume correctly that search works on the actual contents of the page and the Find Friends has the same functionality regardless of the content, I would leave Find Friends as a top level button and put the search as a bar beneath (possibly hidden behind the title, like in the native email app).
- Otherwise, put both Search and Find Friends buttons under a chevron or menu button. This would require another tap for either one and make them less discoverable. This would work well if they're both equally important and not used very often.
- My least preferred option (that still works) is leaving Search as the right button and collapsing Find Friends under the "Me" title. I assume the title isn't tappable right now, but you could add a downward pointing chevron next to it (there are a few apps with this pattern) and make it open a bubble with the Find Friends (and perhaps other options).

BTW - the icon with a person and a plus implies, IMO, "add friends" rather than "find friends".

Answer (score 1):

If you don't consider Find Friend and Search as an entity in the [design principle grouping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principles_of_grouping) (Gestalt law), you should divide the space equally between all four elements.

```
|    Home     |     Me      |   Search    | Find Friend |
```

Ensure that you enforce the same [white space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_space_%28visual_arts%29) between all four elements.